# Efficient way to select all pairs of vertices that share common neighbors in a bipartite network

Tags: python, graph, complexity-theory, igraph, bipartite

I need select all pairs of vertices of the same type that share common neighbors in a bipartite network

For instance:

[image]

In this graph I have: (A,B), (A,C), (B,C), (C,D), (1,2) and (2,3)

I can solve by a quadratic solution:

```
import igraph
import time

def common_neighbors(adjlist, i, j):
    return len(adjlist[i].intersection(adjlist[j]))

def matching_1(graph, row, column):
    adjlist = map(set, graph.get_adjlist())
    matching = []
    dict_edges = dict()
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(i+1, row):
            if common_neighbors(adjlist, i, j) > 0:
                matching.append((i, j))
    dict_edges = dict()
    for i in range(row, row+column):
        for j in range(i+1, row+column):
            if common_neighbors(adjlist, i, j) > 0:
                matching.append((i, j))
    return matching

def matching_2(graph, row, column):
    adjlist = map(set, graph.get_adjlist())
    matching = []
    for vertex in range(row):
        twohops = set((twohop for onehop in adjlist[vertex] for twohop in adjlist[onehop])) -set([vertex])
        for twohop in twohops:
            matching.append((vertex, twohop))
    for vertex in range(row, row+column):
        twohops = set((twohop for onehop in adjlist[vertex] for twohop in adjlist[onehop])) -set([vertex])
        for twohop in twohops:
            matching.append((vertex, twohop))
    return matching

if __name__ == "__main__":

    row, column = 500, 500
    graph = igraph.Graph.Full_Bipartite(row, column)

    tp_start = time.time()
    m = matching_1(graph, row, column)
    print "%.4f" % (time.time()-tp_start)

    tp_start = time.time()
    m = matching_2(graph, row, column)
    print "%.4f" % (time.time()-tp_start)
```

This is the most logical way I can think of doing it. If anyone knows a more efficient way, I am all ears. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically calculating the edge lists of the two bipartite projections of your original network. igraph has a built-in method for this, assuming that your vertices have a vertex attribute named `type` that describes which part of the graph the vertices belong to:

```
>>> g=Graph.Formula("A--1--B--2--C--3--D, A--2")
>>> g.vs["type"] = [name in "ABCD" for name in g.vs["name"]]
>>> g1, g2 = g.bipartite_projection()
>>> [tuple(g1.vs[pair]["name"]) for pair in g1.get_edgelist()]
[('1', '2'), ('2', '3')]
>>> [tuple(g2.vs[pair]["name"]) for pair in g2.get_edgelist()]
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, @tamás. I would like to know more about this function: `bipartite_projection`. I read the documentation but the algorithm has not been specified within the file: [link](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph-pysrc.html#Graph.bipartite_projection). You know which algorithm was used and where this the complete documentation of this function within the igraph webpage?

Comment: Well, there isn't really any specific algorithm behind this - it is a straightforward implementation that follows from the definition of the bipartite projection. The documentation of the corresponding C function is here: http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Bipartite.html#igraph_bipartite_projection

Comment: I appreciate your prompt reply, thanks @Tamás. In this documentation the time complexity is O(|V|*d^2+|E|). But, I can solve this by a quadratic solution. I'm curious about this, how to get this complexity? A reply is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You iterate over all vertices of type 1 of the graph and then for each vertex v, you enumerate all (u, w) pairs of the neighbors of the vertex - each (u, w) pair will be connected in the projection since they share a common neighbor (vertex v itself). Check out the source of `igraph_i_bipartite_projection` in the igraph source code (`src/bipartite.c`, see https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/master/src/bipartite.c#L149 ).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt and very good response to my question. :)